# Internal DVD drive not working

Tags: dvd, eject

I have a Macbook Pro 15 inch, mid 2010 with High Sierra installed (10.13.6)

Recently I tried to put a DVD into the internal DVD drive, but nothing showed up. It made some weird sounds as if it was trying to get the drive running, but it didn't help. So I tried to eject the DVD, but the eject button didn't work as well. I couldn't eject it from Finder either. I tried restart the computer while holding the eject button, but it didn't work. Then I just dropped to get it out.

But whenever I open my computer, it says the weird sounds as if it is trying to run the DVD. It runs 3 times, and then it stops.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The words "Then I just dropped to get it out" are unclear. Is the DVD now still inside the drive, or were you able to remove it?

Comment: Are you trying to see f you can get the DVD  to read or to force eject it?

Comment: No, it is still inside my computer, and I tried to force eject it. Another thing is that when I open up DVD player it gives me this error: There was an initialization error. A valid DVD drive could not be found. [-70012]

Comment: Try `Command-E` as well.  It's also possible you've got two disks jammed in there.  I've removed them with careful use of long needle nose pliers and a bit of force.  Your other option is to remove the drive, disassemble it and remove the disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. All mechanical drives, (particularly CD/DVD drives and old-fashioned hard drives), have a limited lifespan and wear out. 8 years is pretty good actually. I'd recommend the opposite though — just get yourself a $20 external USB CD/DVD drive, and then (when you're ready for it, replace the internal DVD drive with a secondary SSD (I assume you've already replaced the HDD it came with... *right*?) You have a RAID in your laptop!

(Not referral links):

[https://www.amazon.com/LG-Electronics-Portable-External-GP65NB60/dp/B00ODDE33U/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ODDE33U)
[https://www.amazon.com/Optical-SuperDrive-Adapter-Unibody-Macbook/dp/B004FM4UGE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004FM4UGE)

The repair is fairly easy to do yourself:
https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2010+Optical+Drive+Replacement/3074

Comment: Where did you see the OP had RAID in his laptop?

Comment: Thank you for your very great answers, but a long time I found the DVD sticking a little bit out, and then I pulled it out of the drive :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it sounds like your optical drive bit the dust.

The fact that it tries to read a presumably good DVD and can't and you get an error opening DVD Player **AND** can't get the disc out of the drive speaks to likely needing a new drive.

You will need to take it in for repair which will likely mean a replacement optical drive.